# ghdl install (tgingold) : gnatmake not found but exists : usr/local/gnat/bin/gnatmake

Tags: git, vhdl, ghdl

MacOs user : Sierra

Vhdl user too.

- I installed ada-gpl_2017 : ok (path written in .bash_profile)
- I installed ghdl via tgingold's git and return a strange error :

I did:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local                       # ok
make                                                  # ok
sudo make install                                     # not ok
```

The last step returns the following error:

```
make: gnatmake: No such file or directory
```

But it exists in `/usr/local/gnat/bin/gnatmake`. Could you help me to solve this error?

Comment: Did you add `/usr/local/gnat/bin` to your `PATH`?

Comment: > yes of course.

Comment: I found why it did not work.

Comment: you must open the makefile and change the macro's path to gnatmake. Do not forget to restart your computer. thanks

Comment: @Marie you can put that in an answer and mark it as correct so it's more obvious for future readers.

Comment: @scary_jeff : how could I do what you wrote?

Comment: I did that at first (before writing to stackoverflow). But I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem was probably that the `/usr/local/gnat/bin` directory was not part of your `PATH` environment variable (the environment variable that your shell uses to find executables like, for instance, `gnatmake`). The solution is simple: add this directory to the `PATH` environment variable when invoking `make`:

```
sudo make PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gnat/bin install
```

Comment: You don't need gnatmake on the path when using ghdl ... she needs it on the path because she's *building* ghdl.

Comment: You're right, of course, `gnat` is needed only to build GHDL, not to use it once it is installed. I fixed my answer.